# Android - Continuously draw shapes to random locations

Tags: java, android, animation, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm a little new to android animation. I'm working on a project which places a picture of a ball at a random location -after which it will move in circle. I've been successful thus far but now I would like to continuously draw new shapes at different random coordinates. I thought about using a thread by which to draw shapes every few seconds but I can't seem to implement it without screwing everything up.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Also I know that I will have to continuously reset my random coordinates each time too. Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks for any help. My code is below:

```
public class DrawingTheBall extends View {

Bitmap bball; 
int randX, randY;
double theta;


public DrawingTheBall(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    bball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blueball);  
    randX = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*500); 
    randY = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*500);
    theta = 45;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //Radius, angle, and coordinates for circle motion  
    float a = 50;
    float b = 50;
    float r = 50;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    theta = theta + Math.toRadians(2);

    //move ball in circle
    if(x < canvas.getWidth()){
        x = randX + (int) (a +r*Math.cos(theta));
    }else{
        x = 0;
    }
    if(y < canvas.getHeight()){
        y = randY + (int) (b +r*Math.sin(theta));
    }else{
        y = 0;
    }
    Paint p = new Paint();

    //Implement Thread here
      thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                  @Override
                  public void run(){

                    for(int j = 0; j <= 60; j++){

                          //It tells me to change variables to Final
                        //But if I do that it messes up my if statements above
                            canvas.drawBitmap(bball, x, y, p);

                         }
                      };
                      try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } //wait one second
                    }
                  }

                });
                thread.start();

    //canvas.drawBitmap(bball, x, y, p);
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Idea:

1. Implement Runnable and handler
2. Create random coordinate by Random.

   ```
   public class DrawingTheBall extends View implements Runnable {

   final Bitmap bball;
   Random randX, randY;
   double theta;
   Handler handler = new Handler(){
       public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
           invalidate();
           System.out.println("redraw");
       };
   };

   public DrawingTheBall(Context context) {
       super(context);
       bball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               R.drawable.ic_launcher);
       randX = new Random();
       randY = new Random();
       theta = 45;
       new Thread(this).start();
   }

   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       // Radius, angle, and coordinates for circle motion
       float a = 50;
       float b = 50;
       float r = 50;
       int x = 0;
       int y = 0;
       theta = theta + Math.toRadians(2);

       // move ball in circle
       if (x < canvas.getWidth()) {
           x = randX.nextInt(100) + (int) (a + r * Math.cos(theta)); // create
                                                                   // randX
                                                                   // integer
       } else {
           x = 0;
       }
       if (y < canvas.getHeight()) {
           y = randY.nextInt(100) + (int) (b + r * Math.sin(theta));// create
                                                                   // randX
                                                                   // integer
       } else {
           y = 0;
       }
       Paint p = new Paint();
       canvas.drawBitmap(bball, x, y, p);
   }

   public void run() {
       while (true) {
           try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks but sleep(1000) gives me an error, it says I need to create a method called sleep. How do I fix it? I know it's probably simple.